# Simple Console in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, console

I know that Rails Console and IRB can be run from Tools.
But how can i run simple console in RubyMine? (command line for rails s; rails g ... - it is more comfortable for me)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can configure 'bash' as an external tool in Settings | External Tools - then you'll be able to run it in a RubyMine toolwindow.

Comment: thanks, I added C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe as program, and $ProjectFileDir$ as Working Directory